# Google Analytics: Strange numbers - 0 page views, missmatching Time on Site and Session Duration

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I got a hard time understanding these phenomena. This ist a screenshot of a custom report. I know I mixed page & session dimensions, still these numbers doesn't make sense to me.

Background: Tracking via GTM with 2 subdomains (same GTM) | Last 2 colums are calculated metrics based on beforeunload events.

[image: Analytics Screenshot - 3 different pages]

Why are there entries and sessions with 0 page views?

How can the avg time on site be positive when the avg session duration is 0?

Why is the avg time on site 0 when the avg session duration is over 8 min? (last page with no interaction?! Still, this entry B shouldn't be shown then)

Appreciate your input.